# How do electron or proton have charge?

Tags: particle-physics

I mean we know proton and electron posses charged that are opposite to each other and they emit  electromagnetic radiation perpendicular to each other. My question here is where does this charge comes from at the first place . What process is there that provide charge to these subatomic particles ?

Comment: Hi @Garima Johsi and welcome to PSE. The charge is an intrinsic property of a particle, just like its spin... So a particle does not acquire charge, it is "born" with it.

Comment: However, why they are "born" with charge is a rather deep question.

Comment: No need for down votes. This is a reasonable question. Physics is a description of how the universe behaves. Questions about why it is this way often cannot be answered. Sometimes we can say the reason why a complex law works is because it is a consequence of a simpler law. But the simplest laws have no known cause. Sometimes a better theory provides better simple laws that explain more. But so far, nobody knows any reason for why they have charge.

Comment: They just do. https://fs.blog/richard-feynman-on-why-questions/

Comment: *they emit electromagnetic radiation perpendicular to each other* Where did you read this?